# How to get map ms-core.js to load in JavaScript api

Tags: javascript, api

I’m getting the following error when trying to run my program which should load a map using here maps. I’ve loaded all the script codes correctly but get mapsjs-core.js:299 Uncaught C message: "H.Map (Argument #0 null)"stack: "Error↵ at new C (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:11:460)↵ at new Q (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:299:636)↵

I’ve reloaded the scripts from heremaps but to no avail.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If someone from HERE could please advise.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to resolve? If not, can you add the "here-api" tag to this question so the HERE team can easily see this? Thanks!